# Trouble installing Matlab 2014b on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, matlab

I'm aware of this article: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MATLAB and have followed the instructions, which didn't help me. EDIT: Only because I'm stupid, the article is great.

I mounted my matlab 2014b-iso (it's named "R2014b_glnxa64.iso", so I'm very much assuming it's the 64-bit version) and `ls -l` is telling me

```
total 6334
-r--r--r-- 1 root root    3371 Mär 21  2011 activate.ini
dr-xr-xr-x 7 root root    2048 Sep 16 17:18 archives
dr-xr-xr-x 3 root root    2048 Sep 16 17:15 bin
dr-xr-xr-x 3 root root    2048 Sep 16 17:15 etc
dr-xr-xr-x 5 root root    2048 Sep 16 17:16 help
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root   10518 Aug  5 02:11 install
-r--r--r-- 1 root root    9365 Jul 26 09:07 installer_input.txt
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 6340999 Sep 12 16:15 install_guide.pdf
dr-xr-xr-x 4 root root    2048 Sep 16 17:15 java
-r--r--r-- 1 root root   82776 Sep 12 15:23 license.txt
-r--r--r-- 1 root root    8300 Sep  8 23:00 patents.txt
-r--r--r-- 1 root root   15779 Sep  8 23:12 readme.txt
dr-xr-xr-x 3 root root    2048 Sep 16 17:15 sys
-r--r--r-- 1 root root     245 Dez 28  2013 trademarks.txt
-r--r--r-- 1 root root      32 Sep 16 17:31 version.txt
```

so I should have all permissions I need.

However, executing `sudo ./install` results in

```
./install: 1: eval: /media/iso/bin/glnx86/install_unix: not found
```

which is right, since the path is `/media/iso/bin/glnxa64/install_unix`.

Out of curiosity I tried `sudo ./bin/glnxa64/install_unix` and got

```
Error: Cannot locate Java Runtime Environment (JRE).
The directory /media/iso/sys/java/jre/glnx86/jre does not exist.
```

How can I install matlab!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having looked up the line of code in the install script where `glnx86` appears, I got confused first. But now I realized I installed Ubuntu 14.04 ***32 bit***.. Of course, trying to install Matlab 64 bit fails.

Gotta reinstall Ubuntu..

Answer (score 1):

I encountered an almost identical message

```
./install: … /bin/unknown/install_unix: command not found
```

while attempting to install Matlab R2017a on 32-bit Ubuntu 16.04.  For anyone not wanting to install a new operating system, [Matlab R2012a](https://www.mathworks.com/downloads/web_downloads/select_products?dl_action=choose_products&platform_id=56&release_name=R2012a&tab=f) supports 32-bit Linux.  I needed to keep my current operating system, and I was able to successfully install R2012a on my machine.