# Trouble installing MATLAB2014B on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to install MATLAB on my ubuntu 14.04.
When I type following command in terminal

```
sudo ./install
```

I get the following error:

```
./install: 1: eval: /media/panda/MATHWORKS_R2014B/bin/glnxa64/install_unix: not found
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/541610/trouble-installing-matlab-2014b-on-ubuntu-14-04) suggests that you have Ubuntu 32 bit, but you are trying to install 64 bit Matlab. You can check your Ubuntu with `uname -r`.